# Bootstrap 4 - collapse one section when the other expands?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

```js
const cur_url = window.location.href.split('#')[0].split('?')[0],
  body = $('body'),
  menu_toggle = $('.menu-toggle'),
  sidebar_menu = $('#sidebar-menu');

initSidebar = function() {
  let openUpMenu = function() {
    sidebar_menu.find('li').removeClass('active active-sm');
    sidebar_menu.find('li ul').slideUp();
  }

  sidebar_menu.find('a').on('click', function(ev) {
    let $li = $(this).parent();
    $li.is('.active') ? $li.removeClass('active active-sm') : $li.addClass('active');
  });

  // toggle small or large menu
  menu_toggle.on('click', function() {
    if (body.hasClass('nav-md')) {
      sidebar_menu.find('li.active ul').hide();
      sidebar_menu.find('li.active').addClass('active-sm').removeClass('active');
    } else {
      sidebar_menu.find('li.active-sm ul').show();
      sidebar_menu.find('li.active-sm').addClass('active').removeClass('active-sm');
    }

    body.toggleClass('nav-md nav-sm');
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  initSidebar();
});
```

```css
.left_col {
  background: #2A3F54;
}

.nav-sm .container.body .col-md-3.left_col {
  height: calc(100vh - 77px) !important;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

.nav-sm .container.body .right_col {
  margin-left: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.nav-sm .hidden-small {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.nav-sm .side-menu li a {
  text-align: center !important;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.nav-sm .side-menu li a i.toggle-up {
  display: none !important;
}

.nav-sm .side-menu li a i {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100% !important;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.nav-sm .side-menu li.active-sm {
  border-right: 5px solid #1ABB9C;
}

.nav-sm .side-menu li.active-sm ul ul {
  position: static;
  width: 200px;
  background: none;
}

.nav-sm .child-menu li.active {
  border-right: 5px solid #1ABB9C;
}

.nav-sm ul.child-menu {
  left: calc(100% + 5px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 210px;
  z-index: 4000;
  background: #3E5367;
}

.nav-sm ul.child-menu ul {
  position: static;
  width: 200px;
  background: none;
}

.nav-sm ul.child-menu li {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.nav-sm ul.child-menu li a {
  text-align: left !important;
}

.nav-sm>.side-menu>li.active-sm>a {
  color: #1ABB9C !important;
}

.nav-sm .menu-section {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-sm .menu-section h3 {
  display: none;
}

.nav-sm .sidebar-footer a i.fa::before {
  content: "\f054";
}

.menu-section h3 {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(248, 239, 239, 0.059);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.menu-section>ul {
  display: block;
}

.nav-md .main-menu {
  width: 200px;
}

.nav-md .container.body .col-md-3.left_col {
  height: calc(100vh - 77px) !important;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-md .container.body .right_col {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.nav-md ul.child-menu li:before {
  background: #9eb6ca;
  bottom: auto;
  content: "";
  height: 6px;
  left: 12px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  right: auto;
  width: 6px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.nav-md ul.child-menu li:after {
  border-left: 1px solid #9eb6ca;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.nav-md ul.child-menu li:last-child::after {
  bottom: 50%;
}

.main-menu .fa {
  width: 20px;
  opacity: .99;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.nav_menu {
  float: left;
  background: #2A3F54;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  color: #73879C;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Roboto, Arial, "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.471;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body .container.body .right_col {
  margin-top: 37px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: calc(100vh - 96px) !important;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #fff !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #ECF0F1 !important;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  line-height: 32px;
}

.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #D9DEE4;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  width: 220px;
}

.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu.msg_list {
  width: 300px !important;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: #fff !important;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #ECF0F1 !important;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  line-height: 32px;
}

.main_content {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.h1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.h2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.h3 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

a {
  color: #5A738E;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
}

a:visited {
  outline: 0;
}

a:focus {
  outline: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
  outline: 0;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.btn:active:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.btn:active.focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.btn.active:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.btn.focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.btn.active.focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.navbar-header {
  background: #34495E;
}

.navbar-right {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.pg-header .navbar-right {
  margin: 13px;
  width: auto;
  float: right;
}

.pg-header .navbar-right li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
  float: right;
}

.pg-header .dropdown-menu li {
  width: 100%;
}

.pg-header li a i {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.dropdown-item {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
}

.navbar-static-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-header {
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 46px;
}

.sidebar-header:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.sidebar-footer {
  width: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 4px 14px 4px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.sidebar-footer a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar-footer a i {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  color: #fff;
}

.child-menu {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.child-menu>li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.child-menu>li>a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 7px 10px 6px;
}

.child-menu>li>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.child-menu>li>a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.side-menu>li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.side-menu>li>a {
  color: #E7E7E7;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.side-menu>li>a:hover {
  color: #F2F5F7 !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.side-menu>li.active {
  border-right: 5px solid #1ABB9C;
}

.side-menu>li.active>a {
  text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0 -1px 0;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#334556), to(#2C4257)), #2A3F54;
  background: linear-gradient(#334556, #2C4257), #2A3F54;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.16) 0 1px 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.16) 0 1px 0;
}

.child-menu li {
  padding-left: 18px;
}

.child-menu li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
}

.child-menu li li:hover {
  background: none;
}

.child-menu li li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.child-menu li li a.active {
  color: #fff;
}

.child-menu li li.active {
  background: none;
}

.child-menu li.active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
}

.child-menu>li>a {
  color: #E7E7E7;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 4px 5px;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #515356 !important;
}

.top_menu>li>a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #34495E !important;
}

.toggle {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}

.toggle a {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle a i {
  font-size: 26px;
}

header.pg-header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}

footer.pg-footer {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: #2A3F54;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  border: medium none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  left: 0;
  list-style: none outside none;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: none;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 9998;
  border: 1px solid #D9DEE4;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  color: #5A738E;
}

a.user-profile {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.user-profile img {
  width: 29px;
  height: 29px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.nav-logo {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 3px 0 0 8px;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .nav_menu {
    position: static;
  }
  .item {
    display: block;
    display: block;
  }
  .pg-header .navbar-right li {
    position: relative;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .nav-md .container.body .pg-header {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .nav-md .container.body .col-md-3.left_col {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-md .container.body .right_col {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 56px 0 0 0;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .nav-sm .container.body .col-md-3.left_col {
    height: calc(100vh - 77px) !important;
  }
  .item {
    display: block;
  }
}

.nav-link[data-toggle]:not(.collapsed):after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: 17px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/ico" />
  <title>SPA</title>
</head>

<body class="nav-md">
  <div class="container body">
    <div class="col-md-3 left_col">
      <!-- sidebar menu -->
      <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main-menu">
        <div class="menu-section" id="section-1">
          <h3>Menu 1</h3>
          <ul class="nav side-menu accordion-group">
            <li>
              <a href="#menu-section-1" data-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link collapsed"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Menu Section 1</a>
              <ul class="child-menu collapse" id="menu-section-1">
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#menu-section-2" data-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link collapsed"><i class="fa fa-clone"></i> Menu Section 2</a>
              <ul class="child-menu collapse" id="menu-section-2">
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-section" id="section-2">
          <h3>Menu 2</h3>
          <ul class="nav side-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="#multilevel-menu" data-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link collapsed"><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> Multilevel Section</a>
              <ul class="child-menu collapse" id="multilevel-menu">
                <li><a href="#level1_1">Level One</a></li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#level-1" data-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link collapsed">Level One</a>
                  <ul class="child-menu collapse" id="level-1">
                    <li class="sub_menu"><a href="#level2">Level Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#level2_1">Level Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#level2_2">Level Two</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#level1_2">Level One</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-footer">
          <a class="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /sidebar menu -->
    </div>

    <!-- Header: top navigation -->
    <header class="pg-header">
      <div class="nav_menu">
        <div class="nav toggle">
          <a id="menu_toggle" class="menu-toggle ml-2 mr-2"><i class="fa fa-bars text-light"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <!-- /Header: top navigation -->

    <!-- Main: page content -->
    <div class="right_col" id="main-fta-container" role="main">
      <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header">Header</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Main: page content -->

    <!-- Footer: content -->
    <footer class="pg-footer">
      <div class="pull-right text-light">SPA - Powerd by <a href="https://https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SPA">SPA</a></div>
    </footer>
    <!-- /Footer: content -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have a menu that should be able to have multiple sections. Each section has child section that can hold multiple levels of items. I use Bootstrap 4 collapse method to show/hide menu sections. One thing that I would like to see is when one user clicks on one section the other section should collapse. As of now the code is not able to close the previous section. One more thing, if user clicks on the `Item 2` for example, that item is current/active. Then if user clicks on `Item 4` the `Item 2` is still marked as active/current. How to only keep the item that user clicked on active and unmark the previous item?

Here is the link with my code example: https://jsfiddle.net/dmilos89/cyxj7f98/

Answer (score 0):

```
    sidebar_menu.find('a').on('click', function (ev) {
        // access any active `li`s in this `ul` and set inactive
        $(this).closest('ul').find('.active').removeClass('active active-sm')
        // set this `li` active
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active active-sm')
        if ($(this).hasClass('nav-link')) {
          // collapse all menus
          $('#sidebar-menu .child-menu').addClass('collapse')
          // un-collapse selected 
          $(this).closest('li').find('.child-menu').removeClass('collapse')
        }
    });
```

Something like this?

Edit: BTW, I removed your data-toggle="collapse" in my fiddle. It seemed to work as you explained...